# Is it possible to stub meteor methods and publications in cypress tests?

Tags: meteor, cypress

Is it possible to stub meteor methods and publications in cypress tests?

In the docs (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/testing-your-app#Stubbing-the-server) it says:

> This means that instead of resetting the database, or seeding it with
> the state we want, you can force the server to respond with whatever
> you want it to. (...) and even test all of the edge cases, without needing a server.

But I do not find more details about that. All I can find is, that when not using the virtual user in the tests to fill the database, it is possible to call API calls on the app, like so:

```
cy.request('POST', '/test/seed/user', { username: 'jane.lane' })
      .its('body')
      .as('currentUser')
```

In my opinion that is not a "stub". It is a method to "seed" the database.

Is it possible to tell cypress to answer a meteor method in the client code like

```
Meteor.call('getUser', { username: 'jane.lane' }, callbackFunction);
```

with some data, it would give back in production?

Answer (score 0):

I can only show an example using `sinon` to stub Meteor method calls:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(Meteor, 'call')
stub.callsFake(function (name, obj, callback) {
 if (name === 'getUser' && obj.username === 'jane.lane') {
   setTimeout(function () {
     callback(/* your fake data here */)
   })
 }
})
```

That would be of corse a client-side stub. You could also simply override your Meteor method for this one test.

Comment: Seems to be that it isn't possible to import Meteor in a cypress test (`import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';`). I get `Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./specs/cypress/integration/tests/login_spec.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'meteor/meteor'`